# Azure automation, PowerShell to fetch a file in public blob container

Tags: azure, powershell, installation, download, storage

I have a publice fileshare storage, and I want to ask. is it possible to download & install in one go like is there an env for that purpose, or will i need to download with a destination folder and then execute an install of the font i need installed?

Also, will pnp-connect work with a public azure storage folder?
Or is that only for sharepoint?

If not, will

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -OutFile $filePath
```

... work as a connection to my public azure storage?

thanks in advances if anyone have an idea :)

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to download & install in one go like is there an env for that purpose, or will i need to download with a destination folder and then execute an install of the font i need installed?

AFAIK, in a blob container we can keep our files, but we cannot install any executable files in blob.

Use **Get-AzureStorageBlobContent** to get the content of the blob.

#### Workaround

```
$CName = '<ContainerName>'
$downPath = '<Path to download>'
$StorageConnString = '<Storage account Connection String>'
#collect storage accout details
$getStorageAcc = New-AzureStorageContext -ConnectionString $StorageConnString
#Get Blob details
$getBlobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $CName -Context $getStorageAcc
#Download blob
Get-AzureStorageBlobContent `
    -Container $CName -Blob $getBlobs.Name -Destination $downPath `
    -Context $getStorageAcc

# using storage account uri you can download the blob files using "Invoke-WebRequest" or follow below

$BlobFileUri = 'https://<StorageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net/<ContainerName>/<YourFiletoDownload>.txt'
#Generate SAS URI from portal and Add here
$Sasuri = '<SAS URI>'
#Download blob using SAS URI
$URI = "$BlobFileUri$Sasuri"
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($URI, $downPath)
```

#### Result

[image]
[image]